# Trouble for deploy Symfony 4 on my ftp server

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm a dev from symfony 3.3 and i would like to have migrate on symfony 4 but everything i try didn't word for having a working build on my ftp server.

- I have install composer
- Download the demonstration project from symfony with composer
- Install apache bundle with composer

I verify the .htaccess and is there in the "public" folder

With my ssh access, i have launch the server: bin/console server:run

after that i go to my domain, go to the public folder

The toobar is loading perfectly but i don't have any css/js loading

I send a screenshot with what i see on my website

I saw a lot of people speaking about the virtual host but i don't have access to the file with my ftp provider, is it necessary to modify this? Everything was working with symfony 3 so i hope i can still use this provider with symfony 4 (hostinger)

One more thing, when i put the bin/console server:run i got this

```
     [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8002
```

don't know if it's normal :)

and when i navigate on my website, there is nothing mark on my ssh console

https://i.gyazo.com/a40d12ce223ca6429cf2987d9bda18c8.png

https://i.gyazo.com/809330cfc89483e99b7b1f704d789a1d.png

Comment: you shouldn't run symfony with bin/console server:run on an actual server. apache plus some php socket/module/whatever should take care of all of that. however, apache has to be configured to assume the public folder to be the root directory! listening on 127.0.0.1 means only the host itself can access it, which is absolutely reasonable, since the command is usually only used to allow this for dev purposes on your local machine (where you access it from). your apache in general seems to be working, or you wouldn't need to go to {domain}/public anyway.

Comment: and what about the css and js who is not loading? Any idea?

Comment: my guess would be, that your templates give the template path relative to `/public` and not relative to `/`, which will lead to no js/css/images being found. it will probably be fixed, when you either a) add `/public` prefix to all js/css/image paths (bad solution) or b) fix the mapping, such that `/public/something` turns into `/something`, and you should be fine.